# Power series of $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$ at $x=0$

Tags: analysis, power-series

I have to find power series of $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$ at $x=0$ and give its radius of convergence.

I have

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2-z}=\frac{1}{-2-i-x}-\frac{1}{-1-i-x}=\frac{1}{-2-i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{-2-i}}-\frac{1}{-1-i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{-1-i}}$$

But how do I continue with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \frac{1}
{{1 - x}} - \frac{1}
{{2 - x}} \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{1 - x}} - \frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{{1 - \frac{x}
{2}}} =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {x^n }  - \frac{1}
{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^n }}
{{2^n }}}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {1 - \frac{1}
{{2^{n + 1} }}} \right)x^n }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Since the first series has convergence radius $r_1=1$ while the second series has convergence radius $r_2$=2, your series has convergence radius $r=1$. The convergence radius is always the  distance of the center of the series to the closest singularities. In our case the distance between $x_0=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

You use the fact that\begin{align}\frac1{(x-1)(x-2)}&=\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{2-x}\\&=\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac x2}\\&=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)-\frac12\left(1+\frac x2+\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{2^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(1-\frac1{2^2}\right)x+\left(1-\frac1{2^3}\right)x^2+\left(1-\frac1{2^4}\right)x^3+\cdots\end{align}